# Android draw shapes on images and save

Tags: android, gallery, draw, shapes

I have an application that gets image (from gallery or camera) and then I open this image in some Activity. Then I want to draw shapes on this image on tap, these shapes (once drawn) can also be dragged around over the image and removed. After drawing user can save this image with shapes so it can access them later from the application at any time.

I have managed to make image import form gallery or camera to my activity.

My question is I just want a summary of how would this need to be constructed in order to work?  How would I save images with shapes and their positions so they are accessible later? I would also have an activity (I guess?) in my app which would show thumbnails of all images edited so far. I have attached some images for reference (first image is image edit screen, second image is showing thumbnails edited for far, each can be accessible for edit again).

I am a beginner so please bear in mind.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can get idea form this
https://github.com/KishanViramgama/Drawing

Comment: But I am looking for a advice after drawing how to save all this data (images with drawings) so they are accessible later from the app and can be edited again.